# Audio stops on background on simulator (iOS 7.1)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, ios-simulator

Audio stops when you close app. And may start again if you just open Control Center (swipe from bottom). It's really strange.

Everything's fine in iOS 8 simulator and devices. The problem is I can't install iOS 7 on existing devices to test is it a bug in my app or it's a bug in simulator.

`UIBackgroundModes` in info.plist contains `audio` string object. 
Here is how I configure a session on app start:

```
- (void)setAudioSession {
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:true error:nil];
}
```

To play audio I use `AVPlayer` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's iOS 7 simulator only bug.